# Database error handling using Passport and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I've incorporated the authentication code from [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) into my application and everything is working. Now I'm going back to make the database error handling more robust. In the code below (from the tutorial), why do they `throw` the error if they hit a snag with the `save()`? Is there a reason not to handle more gracefully? Perhaps something like:

```
if (err)
    return done(err, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Encountered database error.'));
```

From the tutorial:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    // asynchronous
    // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
    process.nextTick(function() {
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        // check to see if theres already a user with that email
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        } else {
            // if there is no user with that email
            // create the user
            var newUser            = new User();
            // set the user's local credentials
            newUser.local.email    = email;
            newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
            // save the user
            newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                return done(null, newUser);
            });
        }
    });    
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is simple:

```
newUser.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
  return done(null, newUser);
});
```

even in mongoose [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) saving is done without throwing exception.

solution that You're reading is too old: **Dec 04, 2013**.  Why not to read latest documentation from it's pure source?

Read this: http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

BONUS: I would recommend to shorten Your code by using plugin `mongoose` [findOrCreate](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate)

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm thinking, too (I just added the flash message so I can catch it and display an error message to the user).

Comment: Thanks again. Bonus question: what's up with the `process.nextTick()`? I think I understand literally what that function does, but why do we need to push the `findOne()` onto the call stack? It's already wrapped inside a callback function.

Comment: In Your code nextTick has no effect. Idea of next tick is to call wrapped scope after next statement done. So in Your code there is no next statement.  Read this: https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick in this doc You'll see example of foo-bar that explains what it does.

Comment: Huh. OK. Maybe the moral of the story is not to trust the code in online tutorials to the point of second-guessing my own understanding.

Comment: I read/watch tutorials, but also dive into package to see if there's any other example from the package author(s)

Comment: actually if we read this: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args so You'll see that:  "The process.nextTick() method adds the callback to the "next tick queue". Once the current turn of the event loop turn runs to completion, all callbacks currently in the next tick queue will be called.".   but one question: process.nextTick will ignore callback queue and run before that any of that, but why to slow down other operations? there are many operations in app that also need faster handling.

Comment: Huh. I changed all of the code above it returns `done(err)` when the Mongoose functions return `err` (as you suggested) and then generated a database error (by deleting the MongoDB user used by the code) and it still crashes. It happens even if I try to return `done(null, false)`. Is Mongoose throwing the error and not even returning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125724/discussion-between-num8er-and-tcquinn).